# Flask wtf form not validating custom validators

Tags: python, validation, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

So i have a login form and signup form on a single html page. I have custom validators for signup form that are not working.
The ***routes.py*** looks like this

```py
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    login_form = LoginForm(request.form, prefix="login-form")
    regis_form = RegistrationForm(request.form, prefix="register-form")
    return render_template('home.html', login_form=login_form, regis_form=regis_form)


@app.route("/register", methods=['POST'])
def register():
    regis_form  = RegistrationForm(request.form, prefix='register-form')
    if regis_form.validate_on_submit():
        hashed_password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(regis_form.password_regis.data).decode('utf-8')
        user = User(username=regis_form.username_regis.data, email=regis_form.email_regis.data, password=hashed_password)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your account has been created! You are now able to log in', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return redirect(url_for('home'))

@app.route("/login", methods=['POST'])
def login():
    login_form = LoginForm(request.form, prefix='login-form')
    if login_form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=login_form.email_login.data).first()
        if user and bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, login_form.password_login.data):
            login_user(user, remember=login_form.remember.data)
            next_page = request.args.get('next')
            return redirect(next_page) if next_page else redirect(url_for('home'))
        else:
            flash('Login Unsuccessful. Please check email and password', 'danger')
    return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

***forms.py***

```py
class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    username_regis = StringField('Username',
                           validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=5, max=20)])
    email_regis = EmailField('Email',
                        validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password_regis = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit_regis = SubmitField('Sign Up')

    def validate_username_regis(self, username_regis):
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username_regis.data).first()
        if user:
            raise ValidationError('That username is taken. Please choose a different one.')

    def validate_email_regis(self, email_regis):
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email_regis.data).first()
        if user:
            raise ValidationError('That email is taken. Please choose a different one.')



class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    email_login = EmailField('Email',
                        validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password_login = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    remember = BooleanField('Remember Me')
    submit_login = SubmitField('Login')
```

***home.html***

```html
<div>
  <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('login') }}">
      {{ login_form.hidden_tag() }}
      <fieldset class="form-group">
          <div class="form-group">
              {% if login_form.email_login.errors %}
                  {{ login_form.email_login(class="form-control is-invalid") }}
                  <div class="invalid-feedback">
                      {% for error in login_form.email_login.errors %}
                          <span>{{ error }}</span>
                      {% endfor %}
                  </div>
              {% else %}
                  {{ login_form.email_login(class="form-control mb-2", placeholder="Email") }}
              {% endif %}
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              {% if login_form.password_login.errors %}
                  {{ login_form.password_login(class="form-control is-invalid") }}
                  <div class="invalid-feedback">
                      {% for error in login_form.password_login.errors %}
                          <span>{{ error }}</span>
                      {% endfor %}
                  </div>
              {% else %}
                  {{ login_form.password_login(class="form-control mb-2", placeholder="Password") }}
              {% endif %}
          </div>
      </fieldset>
      <div class="form-group">
          {{ login_form.submit_login(class="btn btn-danger") }}
      </div>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="" id="regis">
  <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('register') }}">
      {{ regis_form.hidden_tag() }}
      <fieldset class="form-group">
          <div class="form-group">
              {% if regis_form.username_regis.errors %}
                  {{ regis_form.username_regis(class="form-control form-control-md is-invalid") }}
                  <div class="invalid-feedback">
                      {% for error in regis_form.username_regis.errors %}
                          <span>{{ error }}</span>
                      {% endfor %}
                  </div>
              {% else %}
                  {{ regis_form.username_regis(class="form-control form-control-md mb-2", placeholder="Username") }}
              {% endif %}
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              {% if regis_form.email_regis.errors %}
                  {{ regis_form.email_regis(class="form-control form-control-md is-invalid") }}
                  <div class="invalid-feedback">
                      {% for error in regis_form.email_regis.errors %}
                          <span>{{ error }}</span>
                      {% endfor %}
                  </div>
              {% else %}
                  {{ regis_form.email_regis(class="form-control form-control-md mb-2", placeholder="Email") }}
              {% endif %}
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              {% if regis_form.password_regis.errors %}
                  {{ regis_form.password_regis(class="form-control form-control-md is-invalid") }}
                  <div class="invalid-feedback">
                      {% for error in regis_form.password_regis.errors %}
                          <span>{{ error }}</span>
                      {% endfor %}
                  </div>
              {% else %}
                  {{ regis_form.password_regis(class="form-control form-control-md mb-2", placeholder="Password") }}
              {% endif %}
          </div>
      </fieldset>
      <div class="form-group">
          {{ regis_form.submit_regis(class="btn btn-danger") }}
      </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Previously I had both forms on the same *home* route, custom validators were working but if i submitted *register* form with errors purposefully, then the login form also shows error like *input required*. So to fix that I did this, but now signup form is not validating custom validators

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'?  What happens?  Please include the full error traceback.

Comment: No errors, the form does not validates. and redirects me to home route. when i try to register using credentials that already exists.

Comment: @ewong when i try to submit register form using credentials that are already registered, it should show me error on the form like 'That username is taken. Please choose a different one.' or 'That email is taken. Please choose a different one.' depending on the input but its not showing me these errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your data has failed validation, you execute `return redirect(url_for('home'))`. That results into a `GET` on the home route. That populates a new instance of the form: `regis_form = RegistrationForm(request.form, prefix="register-form")`. Your error information will be lost, it is on a different instance.

To get the error information, your `register()` route will need to `render` the template using  `render_template('home.html', login_form=login_form, regis_form=regis_form)`, not do the redirect. Do not forget to create a new instance of `LoginForm`, otherwise your rendering will fail.